# BigQuery - How to extract insert job errors

Tags: google-bigquery

I am referring to [Jobs: insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert) page and trying to get errors using the response object. But response.getStatus().getErrorResult() is always return null even load is unsuccessful. How to extract errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From response - you should extract [jobId](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#jobReference.jobId) and then use [Jobs: get](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/get) to get [status.state](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#status.state) of the job. Here you can see if job completed (DONE) or not yet (PENDING or RUNNING), so do this till it is completed and when it is - you can look into [status.errorResult](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#status.errorResult) for last error or into [status.errors](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#status.errors) for all errors encountered during the running of the job

Answer (score 0):

Posting the code for Mikhail's answer,

```
    JobReference jobRef = insert.execute().getJobReference();
    System.out.println("Job ID is: " + jobRef.getJobId());

    Boolean Run_Status = true;
    while (Run_Status) {
        Job pollJob = bigquery.jobs().get(projectId, jobRef.getJobId()).execute();
        System.out.println("Job status: " + pollJob.getStatus().getState());
        if (pollJob.getStatus().getState().equals("DONE")) {
            System.out.println(pollJob.getStatus().getErrors());
            Run_Status = false;
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```